# marvosym produce wrong output

Tags: pdftex

I have written these commands, but in the pdf Just there is B.
I do not What I should do!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\Letter
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no problem when I compile your code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
What do you mean by "there is just B"? What output did you expect, and what did you get? Did it fail to compile? What errors did you get? Did it compile but look wrong? Perhaps you could include a picture.

Comment: there is no problem and error with compiling , but the letter symbol doesn't appear on the pdf output, and I can just see B on the pdf as a result of this command

Comment: @FatemehEsmaili Please can you add an image of your real problem? Thank you.

Comment: @FatemehEsmaili, is this code a part of your code, or whole code only is this? If this is a part of code, please add whole code with including other packages used in.

Comment: I only get a “B” if `\Letter` is used in math mode. The issue has already been discussed.

Comment: @ferahfeza,  I want to use the marvosym package in my resume, but it seems that this package does not work properly in my system. I used this commands to see its result in a new tex file and this is my problem.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I have just written my problem for ferahfeza. I have problem with marvosym package and its output in my system. there is no errors when i compile the tex file, but my output is not desirable. thank you